# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

Tags: apex, node.js

I am trying to insert a list of task records on a case using Node.js.

I am getting this error after inserting 4-5 records. I am doing this as a bulk operation.

> UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record.

```
conn1.sobject("Task").create(TaskRecords, function(err, rets) {
                    if (err ) { console.log(err); }
                    for (var i=0; i < rets.length; i++) {
                        if (rets[i].success) {
                          console.log("Created record id : " + rets[i].id);
                        }
                    }                             
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a create, the parent record (e.g. the WhoId and WhatId records) must be locked first. This error means that the record was not available to be locked, presumably because a DML operation or an Apex Code class has already locked the record. When you get this error, you simply need to try again later.